# Are there any reliable English translations of Masechtot Ketanot?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, translation

I am interested in studying masechet Sofrim, which focuses on scribal arts. They are one of the tractates known as [masechtot ketanot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractate).

I have found a very reliable English translation of Avot Derabbi Natan (one of the M.K.). I haven't seen any English translation of Sofrim or the other M.K.'s in the local Judaica store. Does anything exist? I'd rather have a hard-copy book than find it online, but of there is something online, let me know.

Comment: I can't vouch for its reliability, but I believe Rabbi Steinsaltz included _M'gilas Taanis_ in his _shas_. I mention this because you may want to find out whether he also included _masechtos k'tanos_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a reliable English translation of the masechtot published in a single volume and a two-volume edition from the Soncino Press, titled *The Minor Tractates of the Talmud*. The tractates were translated by various scholars under the editorship of Dr. Abraham Cohen, it is no longer in print.

Still, you can find it in [libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/599309/editions) and [used booksellers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GW3O00).

Comment: If you want to buy it, it is apparently available at http://www.alibris.com/Minor-Tractates-of-the-Talmud/book/-90068986?matches=2

Comment: The link for *used* purchase is waaay over priced. If you’re interested in purchasing LMK.

Answer (score 4):

Dr. [Michael Higger](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/higger-michael) translated into English the following *masechtos ketanos*: Sefer Torah, Mezuzah, Tefillin, Zizit, Abadim, Kutim & Gerim. The translations were published in the back of his Hebrew edition, available at HebrewBooks [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40986).

While Soncino in fact also translated these listed, and others, I prefer Higger’s because he critically edited the Hebrew (original) and so it gave him somewhat of “an edge”. However, Soncino’s is nevertheless also a great translation.

Comment: Soncino brings many variations of text which is very useful

Comment: @sam Indeed they do; almost certain they consulted Higger’s edition.

Comment: Ah,very possible ,it sorta rings a bell

Comment: This is a wonderful find - many thanks !

Comment: @mbloch Very welcome. If not for you editing the tags to the original q I prob would never have seen the q altogether.

Comment: @Oliver yes I did it on purpose to re-raise the question as I felt enough time had passed that new readers might have ideas