# Better understanding masechtot ketanot

Tags: torah-study, mishna, tannaim

I am not knowledgeable about *masechtot ketanot*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractate) writes they are essays from the Tannaitic period or later dealing with topics about which no formal tractate exists in the Mishnah. I understand from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75516/11501) they have been translated in English but not in recent times.

I'd like to better understand the centrality and relevance of these *masechtot*. Does the gemara make reference to them? Do later halachic codes rely on them? Would some of these tractates be considered important required reading for an educated Jew?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12880/16706

Comment: If they are indeed Braisos, gra says you need to learn them. And Rav Kanievsky wrote some hefty comentaries on them.

Comment: A number of common practices are sourced in masechet sofrim. Eg reciting *hanerot halalu* in conjunction with kindling Chanukah lights

Comment: I've seen various gemaras quote baraisos from the masechtos ketanos. Namely semachos and kallah. Just do a search on mesoras hashas

Comment: What is that? Sounds cool @robev

Comment: ואומר ואפילו במסכת כלה

Answer (score 2):

1. “Does the gemara make reference to them?”
   Yes, to some.
2. “Do later halachic codes rely on them?”
   Yes, on some.
3. “Would some of these tractates be considered important required reading for an educated Jew?”
   In my opinion, yes. One obvious reason, see 1 & 2.

For more information on the above questions see the prologues of the following  critical editions:

- [Soferim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/22498)
- [Sefer Torah, Mezuzah, Tefillin, Zizit, Abadim, Kutim & Gerim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40986)
- Masechtos Ze’iros, ed. Higger, N.Y. 1929 (cf. DE, below)
- Masechtos Derech Eretz, ed. Higger, N.Y. 1935
- Kallah, ed. Higger, N.Y. 1936
- Semachot (some opine that Semachot and Evel [Rabbasi] are the same), ed. Higger, N.Y. 1931 (republished Jer. 1970); The Tractate Mourning, ed. Dov Zlotnick, Yale University Press 1966

Comment: 1 and 2 can be easily sourced.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Indeed they could and hence I didn’t bother. Besides, Higger already did it. Any interested reader can use the listed resources.

Comment: That perhaps undermines the usage model on this forum

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that I should have included sources/examples for 1 & 2?

Comment: Yes, essentially, otherwise, coupled with even the rest of your answer, this may just be a comment and not properly answering the question.

Comment: Technically, a Yes or No *would* answer OP’s questions; OP didn’t ask for examples. Such a question is essentially asking for a whole discourse on the Minor Tractates. Instead, I provided sources and resources for OP to facilitate “better understanding” - ואידך זיל גמור.